# change color of custom uibarbuttonitem (iOS7)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have 5 UIBarButtonItems and will change the color of only 2.
How can I do that in xcode 5?

Thanks a lot for answering!

What do I have to add to this code in AppDelegate.m ?

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:UIColorFromRGB (0x34AADC)];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[[UIToolbar appearance] setBarTintColor:UIColorFromRGB (0x34AADC)];
```

Comment: have you tried something like `barButtonItemB.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]` directly on the bar buttons themselves?

Comment: All you are doing is setting app-wide parameters. appearances apply to all objects of the same type in your app and the status bar belongs to the app anyway. Where do you set your individual Button's tint color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a method as follows:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[<The class in which you want to set custom color> class], nil] setTintColor:<myColor>];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you give my an example with the color ,,34AADC'' please? Because I'm new in developing iOS apps and don't know how to do this ,,The class in which you want to set custom color''. I'm sorry.

Comment: [UIColor colorWithRed:52/255.0 green:170/255.0 blue:220/255.0 alpha:1.0];

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you created an object for these. for example:

```
UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]init];
```

now you should do:

```
 [navController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

Don't set the entire UINavigationController, set the object.